# Getting the key and value of br.forms() in Mechanize

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

Using Mechanize, I am able to get all the forms of the page.

```
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

For my page, it gives me information like this:

```
<HiddenControl(assoc_term_in=201535) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(CRN_IN=34688) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(start_date_in=03/28/2016) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(end_date_in=06/11/2016) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(SUBJ=ECEC) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(CRSE=451) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(SEC=001) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(LEVL=Undergraduate Quarter) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(CRED=    3.000) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(GMOD=Standard Letter) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(TITLE=Computer Arithmetic) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MESG=DUMMY) (readonly)>
  <SelectControl(RSTS_IN=[*, WR])>
  <HiddenControl(assoc_term_in=201535) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(CRN_IN=31109) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(start_date_in=03/28/2016) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(end_date_in=06/11/2016) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(SUBJ=BIO) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(CRSE=141) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(SEC=073) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(LEVL=Undergraduate Quarter) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(CRED=    0.000) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(GMOD=Non Gradeable Unit) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(TITLE=Essential Biology) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MESG=DUMMY) (readonly)>
  <SelectControl(RSTS_IN=[*, WD])>
```

However, I want to print out just the values within the `f` variable, such as printing just the `TITLE`, `SUBJ` and `CRSE`

```
ECEC 451 Computer Arithmetic
```

I tried using `f.value`, `f.value`, `f['TITLE']`, but no luck.

I got this working before, but I lost the code when I removed that comment to commit the code to version control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a particular value and you know the key:

```
In [18]: response = br.open("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp")

In [19]: f = list(br.forms())

In [20]: f[0].get_value("firstname")
Out[20]: 'Mickey'
In [21]: f[0].get_value("lastname")
Out[21]: 'Mouse'
```

You can access all pairs with `f._pairs()`:

```
for f in br.forms():
    print(f._pairs())

response = br.open("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp")
for f in br.forms():
    print(f)
    print(f._pairs())
```

You see it gives you key,value pairs:

```
<GET http://www.w3schools.com/html/action_page.php application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(firstname=Mickey)>
  <TextControl(lastname=Mouse)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=Submit) (readonly)>>
[('firstname', 'Mickey'), ('lastname', 'Mouse')]
<GET http://www.w3schools.com/html/action_page.php application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(firstname=Mickey)>
  <TextControl(lastname=Mouse)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=Submit) (readonly)>>
[('firstname', 'Mickey'), ('lastname', 'Mouse')]
<GET http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(err_email=)>
  <TextControl(err_url=) (disabled)>
  <TextareaControl(err_desc=)>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>>
[('err_email', ''), ('err_desc', '')]
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try this out and get back to you!

Comment: Hi Padraic. So I see that `f.pairs()` is a tuple, so I must access them by using an index. `for f in br.forms(): for p in f._pairs(): print p[1]`. This is currently one way I am accessing the values within the tuple, however, this prints everything. I want to specify the key, so I converted both `br.forms()` and `f.pairs()` to `list()`, but I am getting the following error: `tuple indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, if you know the key and which form it is in  then calling `the_form.get_value("key")` on the form will get the value you want.

Comment: The issue is, there are more than one key with the same name, thus returning this error: `more than one control matching name 'CRN_IN'`. I decided to use the double for-loop to see if I can loop through the different Controls, but no luck.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, can you share the link?

Comment: Unfortunately the link requires authentication. However, you can see the format of the controls in my post. Those controls are under `f[1]`

Comment: If you want to filter use `for k,v in f[1]._pairs():if k == whatever:` You can also access by control `for cn in f[1].controls:for k, v in cn.pairs()..`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: That did the trick - thanks =). I also have one slightly related question. Instead of specifying the value of a select like this `form['term_in'] = ['201535',]`, can I choose an index instead? The value is currently hardcoded, and can change depending on the school term. But the index stays the same.